# Slow registration of net-snmp scalar

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmpd

Is there any way to get the status of the registration of scalar in net-snmp ?

In my case there are around 14 scalars and registration of those taking time and returning "no such object found" error when I issue snmpget on localhost for ~5 seconds after target configuration and later the reply for snmpget is positive.

Should I keep snmpd in disabled state till the registration of scalars is done ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How are you achieving said registration? Five seconds is a very long time, but you don't understand the practical problem it poses for you. Is "no object found" worse than disabling the entire service for some reason? tl;dr it's up to you...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit   I am using  **netsnmp_register_scalar** **netsnmp_create_handler_registration** for registration.